# When is it possible to arrive from $a$ to $b$ by this procedure?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose that we take two natural numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$.

Then, we may try to arrive at $b$ by starting at $a$ by this set of rules:

1) To arrive at $a_1$ which is such that we have $a< a_1 \leq b$ it is only allowed that we sum $a$ with one of its divisors different from $1$. If $a_1=b$ we are done.

2) If $a_1<b$ then to arrive at $a_2$ which is such that we have $a<a_1<a_2\leq b$ we perform step 1) with $a_1$.

3) Repeat 2) until we arrive at $a_{k(a,b)}=b$

As an example, take $a=12$ and $b=100$, we have $12 \to 16 \to 20 \to 40 \to 80 \to 100$.

As an example where $\gcd (a,b)=1$ take $a=15$ and $b=22$. Then we have $15 \to 18 \to 20 \to 22$.

As an example where $\gcd (a,b)=1$ and where we cannot arrive at $b$, take $a=18$ and $b=23$.

Of course, $k(a,b)$ can be multi-valued since for the example $a=12$ and $b=100$ we also have $12\to 24\to 48\to 96\to 100$. But this question is not about behaviour of $k(a,b)$ (although it could be that its behaviour has some awesome features).

If this procedure exists for some $a$ and $b$ and $a<b$ we may say that $b$ is *reachable* by $a$.

> Can we find some condition(s) on $a$ and $b$ that is(are) both necessary and sufficient to guarantee that $b$ is *reachable* by $a$?

Since I am not sure did I explain this procedurally in a good way by 1), 2) and 3), I will describe here again the procedure in other words. It is very simple: choose natural numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$. We are trying to arrive at $b$ by adding to $a$ some divisor of $a$ different than $1$. Then we arrive at $a_1=a+\alpha_1$ , where $\alpha_1 | a$. Then if we did not arrive at $b$ with that single step, we add to $a_1$ some divisor of $a_1$ different than $1$ to arrive at $a_2=a_1 + \alpha_2$, where $\alpha_2 | a_1$. We repeat this until we arrive at $b$, if possible. The question is: when is this possible?

Comment: Do you have an example of a prime  $ b $  reachable by some  $ a<b $?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN No, since such an example does not exist.

Comment: Does the following shorter description capture your procedure correctly?  "For natural numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a < b$, we say that $b$ is *one-step reachable* from $a$ if $b - a$ is a divisor of $a$ other than $1$.  We say that $b$ is *$n$-step reachable* from $a$ if there is a sequence $a = a_0, a_1, \dotsc, a_n = b$ in which $a_{i + 1}$ is one-step reachable from $a_i$ for all $0 \le i < n$."  Then maybe you want to define $k(a, b)$ to be the set of all $n$ for which $b$ is $n$-step reachable from $a$, or to be the minimum of that set?

Comment: @LSpice I added description of the procedure in other words under the question raised in the text, you will not face any difficulties or ambiguities when reading it.

Comment: Do you know of an example where $a$ is reachable from $b$, but no 'connecting sequence' (in the hopefully obvious sense) has all its terms divisible by $\gcd(a, b)$?

Comment: @LSpice After going through your description of the procedure I think that you completely understood what I meant to say in the text. You can define $k(a,b)$ to be minimal or to be multi-valued (since there, as shown, can exist $a$ and $b$ for which there is more than one way to reach $b$ by starting from $a$.Both definitions lead to, hopefully, fruitfull study, because I think that $k(a,b)$ is very interesting. Why define it in one way when we can define it in at least two ways and so study two different functions.

Comment: @LSpice Yes sir, I do know.

Comment: Sorry; I guess I meant to append to [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282064/when-is-it-possible-to-arrive-from-a-to-b-by-this-procedure#comment695715_282064) "… and, if so, what is it?"

Comment: $$12 \to 15 \to 18 \to 20$$

Comment: But [$(12, 20)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282064/when-is-it-possible-to-arrive-from-a-to-b-by-this-procedure#comment695730_282064) is not an example where *no* connecting sequence has all terms divisible by $\gcd(a, b)$, because there is a connecting sequence $12 \to 18 \to 20$ (or just $12 \to 14 \to 16 \to 18 \to 20$).

Comment: @LSpice Ah, I did not read carefully your question. Then it depends on the way we reach $b$, obviously.  But $k(a,b)$ is here worth studying, especially multi-valued definition of it.

Comment: I do not know does GCD always must divide at least one *intermediate* sequence. @LSpice

Comment: @LSpice Do we have an example where number of steps does not divide neither $a$ nor $b$? Edit: Yes, we have $9 \to 12 \to 15$.

Comment: But do we have if we count zero-th step?

Answer (score 3):

When $\gcd(a,b)>1$, then we can reach $b$ from $a$ by simply repeatedly adding $\gcd(a,b)$.

The least reachable number (LRN) from $a$ is adding its smallest prime divisor, and the greatest "arrivable" number (GAN) to $b$ is subtracting its smallest prime divisor. LRNs and GANs are always even (when defined). Since even numbers have $\gcd$ at least $2$, they are reachable when the difference between $a$ and $b$ is "large".

So the full statement is:

for $a<b$, $a$ can arrive at $b$ iff exactly one of the following holds:

1. $a$ can arrive at $b$ in $1$ step $\iff 1<b-a=\gcd(a,b)$
2. $a$ can arrive at $b$ in $2$ or more steps $\iff$ GAN of $b$ exists and is at least LRN of $a$

Sufficiency is constructive and necessity is obvious by definition of LRN and GAN.

Comment: You can reword it to two exclusive conditions, amounting to your 1. and the last half of your 4. Gerhard "Brevity:  The Soul Of Math?" Paseman, 2017.09.26.

Comment: 1 and last half of 4 weren't quite exclusive, but now they are.

Answer (score 1):

Let lpf stand for least prime factor.  (Assuming gcd(a,b) is 1 and also both are larger than 1,) If b is at least as big as a plus lpf(a) plus lpf(b), then you can reach b from a.  This is because you can almost always take steps of size 2 to reach the goal.  When you can't take a step of size 2, then b must be at most lpf(a) plus lpf(b) plus a, and if b is reachable at all it must be at least that big.

Gerhard "Taking Small Steps Is Easier" Paseman, 2017.09.26.

Comment: Of course, if gcd(a,b) is bigger than 1, then it is possible, especially if b-a is the least prime factor of both b and a.  Gerhard "Also Leaves That To Reader" Paseman, 2017.09.26.

Comment: Further, one can always take a step to reach an even number, so an upper bound for minimal k(a,b) is 2 log_2 b .  Gerhard "And Lower Bound Of Zero" Paseman, 2017.09.26.

Comment: Why $k(a,b)$ seems to be always divisor either of $a$ or $b$ or both?

Comment: Sorry, it is not always the case that it is so.

Comment: It does not need to be. Consider a and b squares of primes which differ by two. K can be 4 or 5, depending on how you count it.  Gerhard "There Are Many Other Examples" Paseman, 2017.09.27.

Comment: Is there any hope to determine generally number of values of k, (since for some choices of a and b (almost all, probably) there is more than one way to arrive from a to b).? k is obviously multi-valued almost always.

Comment: Suppose a and b are multiples of 6.  There are at least $3^{(b-a)/6}$ paths to take involving any number from $(b-a)/6$ steps all the way up to $(b-a)/2$ steps.  In general it is not clear what the utility is of knowing possible values of k(a,b).  Gerhard "Unsure How To Use It" Paseman, 2017.09.27.